# LoadPicture method failing

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully loaded an image into Oracle table.  When I try to retrieve the same image to an image control in VBA,  the LoadPicture method is failing.  Here is the code I used.

```
Private Sub Image_Retreive()

    Dim v_RecId As Long
    Dim v_Str As String

    With cn
        .Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & cboDsn.Value & ";" & _
                            "User ID=" & txtuser.Value & ";" & _
                            "Password=" & txtpwd.Value & ";"
        .Open
    End With

    Rs.Open "select image,file_name from images where file_name=" & "'" & _ 
             fsys.GetFileName(txtFileName.Value) & "'", _
             cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    Strm.Open
    Strm.Type = adTypeBinary
    Strm.Write (Rs.Fields(0).Value)
    Image1.Visible = True

    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Rs.Fields(1).Value)

    Rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Strm.Close
    Set Strm = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set Rs = Nothing
```

Tried saving to local file:

```
If v_Image_Size > 0 Then 
    'Write the content of the stream object to a file 
    Strm.SaveToFile ("c:\temp\" & Rs.Fields(1).Value), adSaveCreateOverWrite 
    'Load the temp Picture into the Image control 
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\temp\" & Rs.Fields(1).Value) 
    'imgPhoto.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\temp\emp.bmp") 
Else 
    MsgBox "Error reading the Photo" 
End If
```

Got this error:

> > Runtime Error -2147418113(8000ffff) Method 'LoadPicture' of object '_Application' failed

Comment: The same code worked a while ago.  Now I am getting the following error.                
 Run time error 2220
Microsoft Access can not open file 'IMG_0125.JPG'

Comment: Your error mentions Access but you're using Excel/Oracle?

Comment: Hi Tim.  I am using Oracle.  Don't know why it is telling Access.  If you look at my code above , I am using the provider  :  Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"

Comment: `Rs.Fields(1).Value` would be the second field in your recordset, but don't you want the `image`, which would be `Fields(0)` ?  If that's not the problem then consider writing the image out to a temp file and loading it from there.

Comment: The recordset starts with Zero.  so the rs.field(0)  is  image  and rs.fields(1) is the file_name.  So there is not problem with the code.  Let me try  your suggestions if that works.

Comment: So the file in the fileName field is an existing file accessible to your workbook?  What are you doing with the Stream - you don't seem to use it.

Comment: Stream is defined in the Module globally  and set as strm  which I am using in the code.

Comment: As you advised,  I have first written the image from the db to a local location and then tried to load  that to the image control.  That also failed.

Comment: (1) you write to the stream but then the next thing you do with it is close it.  (2) Writing to a temp file works fine for me - if it fails for you it would be useful to update your question with the code you used, and the error you got when you ran it.

Comment: If v_Image_Size > 0 Then
        'Write the content of the stream object to a file
        Strm.SaveToFile ("c:\temp\" & Rs.Fields(1).Value), adSaveCreateOverWrite
       
        'Load the temp Picture into the Image control
        Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("c:\temp\" & Rs.Fields(1).Value)
        'imgPhoto.Picture = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\temp\emp.bmp")
    Else
        MsgBox "Error reading the Photo"
    End If

Comment: I get the below error :  Runtime Error -2147418113(8000ffff)
Method 'LoadPicture' of object '_Application' failed

Comment: When adding code it's easier to read if you update your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim stm As New ADODB.Stream
Dim tmpFileName

'get a temporary file name
tmpFileName = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & "\" & fso.GetTempName

'open a recordset "rs"

With stm
    .Type = adTypeBinary
    .Open
    .Write rs.Fields(0).Value   'write image bytes to stream
    .SaveToFile tmpFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
End With
Sheet1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(tmpFileName)
```

Comment: I have used your code but still get Runtime Error -2147418113(8000ffff) Method 'LoadPicture' of object '_Application' failed

Comment: If you locate the temporary file can you open it?  What format is the image?

Comment: The file type is TMP file  and I am able to open it using mspaint.

Comment: Can you manually set the image control's Picture property to that file and does it display correctly?

Comment: Hi Tim  I have figured out where I am going wrong even after using your code.  There is no issue with your code.  I have removed some unncessary References  (Tools/references)  which are causing some kind of conflicts and  producing errors.  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out